# C++ struct with length of list as parameter

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to use a function that take a struct as parameter.

```
/**
* @param chunk A vector of C-style structs to hold the samples.
* @param timestamps A vector to hold the time stamps.
* @return True if some data was obtained.
*/
template<class T> bool the_function(std::vector<T> &C, std::vector<double> &timest){
    T sample;
    C.clear();
    timest.clear();
    while (double ts=other_function(sample,0.0)) {
        C.push_back(sample);
        timest.push_back(ts);
    }
    return !chunk.empty();
}
```

In an example (which works fine), the struct defines a list/vector (I don't know which one is correct) of a fixed size.

```
using namespace std

struct sample {
    float d[64];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Some stuff is made

    vector<sample> result;
    vector<double> ts;
    if (double timest = the_function(result, ts)){
        cout << timest << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

But I want to use the same function with a list size *n* that I can choose.

I tried to add a parameter to the struct to allow me to choose the size :

```
template <int T>
struct channels {
    float d[T];
};
```

And to use it, I used it like in the example :

```
const int n = function_count(); 
// function_count is a function from a class that return an int
vector<channels<n> > result;
vector<double> ts;
```

But I've got the error at the line where I declare result :
*error: the value of 'n' is not usable in a constant expression*

I tried to use

```
const int n = 64;
```

and it worked, so I think that the function_count makes the difference, but the function_count just return an int.

So do I have to use another kind of *struct*? How can I create a struct that can be used with parameters defined by a function?

**EDIT**

I want to find a solution without modifying the `function_count` and `the_function`, because I didn't made those two functions.

I tried to use only vector to declare `result`, the compilation works, but when it try to use it, I've got the error : `Got an exception: An argument was incorrectly specified.`

Comment: Why are you defining your own oddball template container class instead of just using `std::vector`?

Comment: In short templates work at compile time and `function_count` runs at runtime. You can either try to make `function_count` `constexpr` or just make `int T` a runtime variable like `std::vector` does.

Answer (score 3):

Size of `std::vector` is auto adjustable i.e. its size can increase or decrease as need. So just create the vector of an appropriate type.

- to add element use function `void push_back (const value_type& val);` of `std::vector`
- to delete element use function `void pop_back();` of `std::vector`

You can also create a vector with initial size set. For example, the following sets the size of vector `vec` to 5:

```
std::vector<float> vec(5);
```

You can [get more information about vector here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Are you sure that `vec.size() == 5` when you do `std::vector<float> vec(4)`?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke It was typo error. Corrected now. Thanks for your attention:)

Comment: If I want to use `std::vector`, I have to declare _result_ as `vector<vector<float> > result` ? And so, how can I say that the "second" vector has a len of 5?

Comment: @Cataboum You can't be sure from line `vector<vector<float> > result`; but you can set size of `vector<float>` to 5 when creating it.

Answer (score 0):

`const` and `constexpr` are different.

template argument requires constant expression, so you should modify your code to something like:

```
constexpr int function_count() { return 64; }

void foo()
{
    // ...
    constexpr int n = function_count(); 
    std::vector<channels<n> > result;
    // ...
 }
```

If `function_count` cannot be `constexpr`, you have to change `struct channels` to also be dynamic as for example:

```
struct channels {
    std::vector<float> d;
};
```